# Is "the" necessary in "the number of the nodes", "the list of the handles" and similar phrases?

Tags: definite-article, of-phrases

I wrote:

> In this formula, **the number of the nodes** is multiplied by (H + P) because for each node, it is checked against **the list of the handles**, and if a match is found, a pattern is retrieved from **the list of the patterns**.

In this sentence, *patterns*, *nodes*, and *handles* are specific to the reader then I used "the" before them, I just want to double sure that the sentence above required the second "the" in of-phrases and it's not equivalent to:

> In this formula, **the number of nodes** is multiplied by (H + P) because for each node, it is checked against **the list of handles**, and if a match is found, a pattern is retrieved from **the list of patterns**.

Are they equal in the context I described?

What about the following sentences:

> the time complexity is O(N * (H + P)) where N is **the number of the DOM-tree nodes**, H is the number of handles and P is the number of the patterns. ...
>
> These operations depend on **the size of the handles**, H, and **the size of the patterns**, P.

Is the second "the" extra in this sentence too? because I feel I need to emphasize the items, so I need "the".

Comment: No, you can forego **the** there.  the number of nodes is .... the list of handles... the list of patterns

Comment: @TRomano thank you! Is there any rule for that? I mean in which phrases is it possible?

Comment: There's no need to use the article when the *of*-phrase qualifies the preceding noun like an attributive form (the nodes list...the handles list...the patterns list -> the list of nodes...the list of handles...the list of patterns). But it isn't ungrammatical to use **the**. Consider: *The White House is throwing a gala. Here is the list of dignitaries*. That form is pretty much equivalent to the adjectival "Here is the *dignitaries list*...".   If you use the article (the list of *the* dignitaries)  you're referring to the dignitaries who appear on the list rather than to the type of list.

Comment: @TRomano thank you, I think your comment could be the answer.

Comment: @TRomano I added another sentence in which I used *the size of the handles*, I feel it's not an attributive form and needs "the" after "of", right?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use the second "the" in your example.

The determiner "the" is used to signify a particular object, which in your case is either "number" or "list"

> the number
>   the list

If you had a case of nodes in a set **A** and nodes in a set **B** and only wanted to reference either **A** or **B**, you might write

> the number of *the* **A** nodes
>   the number of *the* nodes in **A**
>   the number of nodes in **A**

In your second part

> the time complexity is O(N * (H + P)) where N is the number of the DOM-tree nodes, H is the number of handles and P is the number of <s>the</s> patterns...
>
> These operations depend on the size of **the** handles (H) and the size of **the** patterns (P).

Since you are using the "**the** +plural" pattern it is equivalent to "**each** +singular"

> These operations depend on the size of **each** handle (H) and the size of **each** pattern (P).

unless it is the *name* of a group

> My friend has two daughters and we call his wife and daughters: *The Ladies*.

which refers to all three (note capitalization), however

> *The Ladies* in the band are all trained musicians.

refers to each woman assuming they are three *other* women.

Comment: Thank you, I added another related sentence to my question, could you please consider that too?

Comment: By "the size of the handles" I mean the number of handles or the size of the handles set. I thought the size and number are equivalent in my sentence. Should I again use "the size of handles" or simply "the number of handles"?